# protect passwords from pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, github

Recently I became quite active at Github and created a few projects with online APIs and stuff, I have integrated my projects with Netlify and Heroku through Github. Now GitHub is sending me emails like [image: mail] .

Is there any way that I can avoid committing keys to Github but still can access hosted sites integrated with Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the token is only needed in certain contexts (e.g. during a job on CI) you could use an environment variable for it; or in the case of GitHub Actions Workflows - you can use a repository secret, by going to your repo -> settings -> secrets

example related to Netlify:
https://www.hvitfeldt.me/blog/bookdown-netlify-github-actions/

Comment: thanks.. this was very useful. Can I use other tokens like client id, secret key, etc into these secrets? will they be accessible afterward?

Comment: these secrets are accessible in the context of a GitHub Action Workflow